# How to make a horizontal ScrollView with images stretch to 100% width and remain scrollable in React Native?

Tags: react-native, image, resize, responsive-images, imagebackground

> I have a horizontal ScrollView in my React Native app that displays images fetched from a data source. I want the ScrollView to stretch to 100% width of its container and remain scrollable horizontally.
>
> How can I make the ScrollView stretch to 100% width and remain scrollable? Here's a simplified version of my code:
>
> ```
> <ScrollView
>   horizontal
>   showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
>   style={styles.imageContainer}
> >
>   {selectedItem.images.map((image, index) => (
>     <Image
>      key={index}
>      source={{ uri: image.src }}
>      style={styles.imageBackground}
>      resizeMode="contain"
>     />
>   ))}
> </ScrollView>
>
> //STYLES
> const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
>
> const styles = StyleSheet.create({
>    imageContainer: {
>      borderWidth:1,
>    },
>    imageBackground: {
>       width: width - 24,
>       height: (width - 24) * 0.75,
>       margin: 5,
>    },
> });
> ```

I want the ScrollView to stretch to 100% width of its container and remain scrollable horizontally.

I've tried setting **`minWidth`** to **`'100%'`** in the **`contentContainerStyle`** , but it's not working as expected. How can I achieve this layout with a horizontally scrollable ScrollView that stretches to 100% width?.

// IGNORE THE GRAY BORDER
[image]

Comment: why don't you use snap crousel? react-native-snap-carousel ? it's simple

Comment: ok lemme try ,but is there any other solution without installing any other package.

Comment: it will require extreme customization and I don't think it's gonna be that sugar with all the devices. as a matter of fact, I don't think it's workable the way you are trying to do it.